# Problem with embed library installation -- *** caught segfault *** address 0x7f87b33be008, cause 'invalid permissions'

Tags: r, tidymodels

Trying to install embed library from tidymodels R packages, I get the following error. Also my session info details are provided.

```
install.packages("embed")
Installing package into ‘/home/roxana/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
probando la URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/embed_0.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 46880 bytes (45 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 45 KB

* installing *source* package ‘embed’ ...
** package ‘embed’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x7f87b33be008, cause 'invalid permissions'

Traceback:
 1: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
 2: library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib)
 3: loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]])
 4: asNamespace(ns)
 5: namespaceImportFrom(ns, loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc,     .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]), i[[2L]], from = package)
 6: loadNamespace(package = package, lib.loc = lib.loc, keep.source = keep.source,     keep.parse.data = keep.parse.data, partial = TRUE)
 7: withCallingHandlers(expr, packageStartupMessage = function(c) invokeRestart("muffleMessage"))
 8: suppressPackageStartupMessages(loadNamespace(package = package,     lib.loc = lib.loc, keep.source = keep.source, keep.parse.data = keep.parse.data,     partial = TRUE))
 9: code2LazyLoadDB(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, keep.source = keep.source,     keep.parse.data = keep.parse.data, compress = compress, set.install.dir = set.install.dir)
10: tools:::makeLazyLoading("embed", "/home/roxana/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/00LOCK-embed/00new",     keep.source = FALSE, keep.parse.data = FALSE, set.install.dir = "/home/roxana/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/embed")
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘embed’
* removing ‘/home/roxana/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/embed’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘embed’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpI8ExsC/downloaded_packages’
```

I would like to know what   *** caught segfault ***
address 0x7f87b33be008, cause 'invalid permissions' means

### My sessionInfo() details as follows:

```
 R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) 
 os Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS system x86_64, linux-gnu 
 ui RStudio language
 es_AR:es collate es_AR.UTF-8 ctype 
 es_AR.UTF-8 tz America/Argentina/Cordoba 
 date 2020-09-01
```

sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=es_AR.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C LC_TIME=es_AR.UTF-8
[4] LC_COLLATE=es_AR.UTF-8 LC_MONETARY=es_AR.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=es_AR.UTF-8
[7] LC_PAPER=es_AR.UTF-8 LC_NAME=C LC_ADDRESS=C
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C LC_MEASUREMENT=es_AR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.3 Matrix_1.2-18 magrittr_1.5 R6_2.4.1 generics_0.0.2
[6] tools_3.6.3 whisker_0.4 base64enc_0.1-3 Rcpp_1.0.5 reticulate_1.16
[11] keras_2.3.0.0 tensorflow_2.2.0 grid_3.6.3 zeallot_0.1.0 jsonlite_1.7.0
[16] tfruns_1.4 lattice_0.20-40
```

Comment: You might consider using RStudio's [Public Package Manager](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360046703913-FAQ-for-Public-RStudio-Package-Manager) to install this as a binary instead of from source, since you are having trouble building it.

Comment: I once had this `segmentation fault` error when I tried to install `tensorflow` on PC with a decade old CPU. It was because `tensorflow` was compiled with an instruction set that is not compatible with my old CPU. If you have an old CPU, you can test by installing `tensorflow` separately and making sure it loads with no errors.   As I understand `embed` needs `keras`, which in turn needs `tensorflow`.